# Parse content inside all HTML elements with class .mod in HTML document with PHP

Tags: php, html-parsing

How can I parse the contents of the class "mod" (`.mod`) in an HTML document using PHP.

If it is possible to use DOMDocument then please tell me how to do it with DOMDocument.

I am currently using the following to get the contents in between the `<title>` tags (`<title>` and `</title>`)

```
$this->document = new DOMDocument();
$title = $this->document->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

But there are other elements on the page of different elements types that share the class "mod" (.mod), how can I get the contents of those elements?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)

```
$path = new DOMXPath($this->document);
$nodes = $path->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' mod ')]");
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what the second line does? Especially the part inside `query("");`? And by the looks of this, this would return an array of all elements with the class mod. After that, I would iterate through the array using a `foreach(){}`, but how would I get the contents out of each node? By contents I mean inside each element with the class .mod ?

Comment: @JayGatz I took this from a project i did but I did some googling to get the actual xpath and I cant even remember half of whats going on in there. Try looking up the constructs in an xpath tutorial. Also can't you just use the nodes' `nodeValue` property to get their contents.